# Ionic 2 Facebook Login - 'App Not Setup' & 'Not Logged in' & 'Given URL is not allowed' Errors

Tags: javascript, ios, facebook, cordova, ionic2

I am trying to implement the Facebook Login API from the Ionic Native library, and have a button in my application that opens up the Facebook login window. However, when that window opens on my iOS device, the following error first appeared.

[image: Ionic 2 Facebook Login Error]

Then, I began receiving a new error after executing the following commands in terminal:

```
$ ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-facebook4 --variable APP_ID="123456789" --variable APP_NAME="myApplication"
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/facebook
```

[image: New Login error.]

This issue finally resolved itself after 1 day of inactivity, and then I made my app public by clicking on this in the `App Review` tab of the Facebook Developers site.

[image: Make App Public]

Now, I am receiving yet another error, which should have been fixed by making the app public. Here is the error:

`App Not Setup: The developers of this app have not set up this app properly for Facebook Login.`

Here is the relevant code for this implementation. I have made sure to include the correct `APP ID` in all relevant variables, and the code, itself, is not causing any errors. It is simply the case that the login is not communicating with my app.

In `package.json`:

```
 {
  "name": "twine-app",
  "author": "Anthony Krivonos",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.1",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^3.4.4",
    "@ionic-native/facebook": "^3.4.4",
    "@ionic/cloud-angular": "^0.11.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "1.1.7",
    "angular2-elastic": "^0.13.0",
    "firebase": "^3.7.5",
    "ionic-angular": "2.2.0",
    "ionic-native": "^2.9.0",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "^5.2.0",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
    "typescript": "^2.2.2",
    "zone.js": "0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.1.4",
    "typescript": "2.0.9"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [],
  "description": "Twine: An Ionic project",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://twineme@bitbucket.org/twine-app/twine-app.git"
  },
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

In `app.component.ts`:

```
platform.ready().then(() => {
        let env = this;
        NativeStorage.getItem('user')
        .then(function (data) {
              env.nav.push(FeedPage);
              Splashscreen.hide();
        }, function (error) {
              env.nav.push(OnboardingPage);
              Splashscreen.hide();
        });
              StatusBar.styleDefault();
              StatusBar.overlaysWebView(false);
              Splashscreen.hide();
  });
```

In `onboarding.ts` (Code by `Sampath`):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Facebook, FacebookLoginResponse } from '@ionic-native/facebook';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public fb: Facebook) {

  }

  fbLogin(): void {
    this.fb.login(['public_profile', 'user_friends', 'email'])
      .then((res: FacebookLoginResponse) => console.log('Logged into Facebook!', res))
      .catch(e => console.log('Error logging into Facebook', e));
  }

}
```

I have scoured several different websites and forums for solutions, and seemed to have come up with no way of fixing this error. Most answers suggest to add a new platform in the Facebook developer portal with the app's Site URL, but my app runs off `localhost`. Additionally, I have installed all necessary plugins. Does anyone understand what may be causing this issue? Thank you so much in advance.

*Edit:* **DO NOT** suggest that I should make the app public via the Facebook Developer portal, because my question clearly outlines that I have done so already. Thanks.

*Edit 2:* I have tried `Sampath`'s solution, and login works perfectly. This reaffirms that there is an issue with the above code. However, I cannot seem to pinpoint it after days of work. Here's a screenshot.

[image: Twine login using Sampath's solution.]

Comment: can you show your `package.json` file?

Comment: Included `package.json` in the description

Comment: is this not working only on iOS device or?

Comment: So far, I have tested it only on iOS: on my iPhone and on Xcode.

Comment: Is there any possibility to put this on "Ionic view"? Then I can test with Android device?

Comment: The button does not activate on Ionic View, unfortunately. The Facebook Cordova plugin only runs on native apps.

Comment: I'm getting a new error, will update the question again.

Comment: You're Wrong here `The Facebook Cordova plugin only runs on native apps`. Ionic view is running on a native device.So you can run any plugin on it.I have done so many.

Comment: Well, you can be assured it does not work with my implementation. Maybe, that's another issue. I'll message you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139990/discussion-between-anthony-krivonos-and-sampath).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it! In the end, my app was configured properly on the Facebook API, and the implementation by `Sampath` worked like a charm. Here was my issue:

The entire time, I had been running the Ionic 2 app off a directory in my iCloud Drive on my MacBook. Since iCloud consistently updates any minor file changes, I was never able to do a complete iOS build using `ionic build ios`, and had to exit early using `^C`. By keeping my project in a directory outside my iCloud drive, which in this case was the directory under the username, I was able to do a complete build with no errors!

> In short, **check out `Sampath`'s solution code**, and make sure you
>   **are not running your Ionic 2 project off iCloud Drive**.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**

It is working fine for me.It seems your issue with facebook's app settings section.Please let me know if you need any help on that section too.

**Play with** [**Git Repo**](https://github.com/Sampath-Lokuge/FacebookLogin).

[image]

***home.ts***

```
import { Facebook, FacebookLoginResponse } from '@ionic-native/facebook';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public fb: Facebook) {

  }

  fbLogin(): void {
    this.fb.login(['public_profile', 'user_friends', 'email'])
      .then((res: FacebookLoginResponse) => console.log('Logged into Facebook!', res))
      .catch(e => console.log('Error logging into Facebook', e));
  }

}
```

***app.module.ts***

```
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { Facebook } from '@ionic-native/facebook';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  providers: [
    Facebook
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

***home.html***

```
<button ion-button block type="button" (click)="fbLogin()">Fb Login</button>
```

**Old Answer**

I can see 3 issues on your `package.json` file.

*Issue 1:*

You have to remove `"ionic-native": "2.4.1",` module from it.

*Issue 2:*

You have to use `"@ionic/app-scripts": "1.1.4",` instead of  `"@ionic/app-scripts": "1.0.0",`

*Issue 3:*

You have to use `"ionic-angular": "2.2.0",` instead of `"ionic-angular": "2.0.1",`

After all above changes run `npm i`

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion but this, unfortunately, does not solve the issue. I tried updating every one of my packages.

Comment: can you show the latest `package.json`? put that on your post above under **Update** section.

Comment: Done. Do you believe it is an issue with my dependencies? I believe it may actually be an issue with my implementation of the Facebook API, but I have yet to uncover an answer.

Comment: hmm.. Are you using this native plugin? https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/facebook/

Comment: Done. I am now receiving a new error. Please check the updated question above! Thanks for the progress.

Comment: I have done it successfully.please see the **Update** section on my post.

Comment: I have added `gif`.please see that too.

Comment: any feedback for this?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have spent all night yesterday working on this and no luck. I have tried your method, the Firebase method, Auth, and FacebookAuth, but still no luck. Perhaps it has something to do with the Facebook app configuration, but I am almost certain every detail is correct. I'll update my question to include every screen later today.

Comment: did you fork my solution and test that? you just need to change the app name and id.If that too not working means, definitely you have a problem with your app settings on FB portal. Hope you can run my solution on Android emulator too if you don't have an android device.

Comment: Your solution works with my Facebook app! However, when I try to use your exact implementation of the Facebook Login in my app, it does not seem to work. I have updated all my dependencies and edited the question to include the changes. Perhaps the versions I am using are still unsupported?

Comment: You're very close now.Now you have a problem with `package.json` again.If you need to use angular 4 then change it like this: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-conference-app/blob/master/package.json otherwise use my repo's like a file.Either case you must remove `"ionic-native": "^2.9.0",`.

Comment: After spending all day trying to fix this issue yesterday, I am still not having any luck. I will try to migrate my code into your implementation today as a last resort. I removed `ionic-native`, but have several imports from this source, including `Splashscreen` and `StatusBar`. Is the only alternative to this using each individual import such as `@ionic/status-bar`? Additionally, I have reverted back to Angular 2 and am still receiving the same error.

Comment: Oh..This is the working solution for you.Start your project using my git repo fork.After that implement your app, component by component (copy/past) inside the my git fork.You always need to put huge attention each and every component where you'll copy/past.check whether is there any errors while you're doing so.If you did this 2 days back, I think now you have a working solution :D

Comment: Thanks for all your help! I got it to work using a different solution, but you definitely really helped me along the way. Check out the solution I posted on this question!

Comment: Great.Nice to see where you have a working app now :)